# Declaration of operator function inside struct

Tags: c++, struct, functor

I was reading this document for templates:

[An Idiot's Guide to C++ Templates - Part 2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/268849/An-Idiots-Guide-to-Cplusplus-Templates-Part-2)

I came across one definition that I did not understand:

```
struct Currency
{
  int Dollar;
  int Cents;

  operator double()
  {
    return Dollar + (double)Cents/100;
  }
};
```

It involves the definition of the `operator double()` function inside the struct body.

What exactly is this, and what does it do?

At first, I thought this was a functor, but a functor definition looks like this:

`int operator ()`

Comment: Google "conversion operator". And `operator()` isn't a "functor", it's an overloaded function call operator. The whole class/struct that contains one is a functor.

Comment: A [decent C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would have taught you that it's a *conversion* operator. It allows objects of type `Currency` to be used as a `double` value. Implicit conversion operators like this are usually not common, and could lead to unexpected problems.

Comment: [User-defined conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator)

Comment: don't be an idiot and don't trust someone who calls you like that. Try here instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: To add to the above description, it's the opposite of a constructor like `Currency(double);`, which allows implicit conversions from `double` to `Currency`. Again, allowing such implicit conversions could lead to problems.

Comment: the article is terrible imho. Their sole motivation to provide a implicit conversion to `double` is that they want to avoid writing a proper `<<` overload, because they consider it "simpler" to teach trash than to explain things the proper way

Comment: In addition, `double` for currency is not ideal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `operator double()` makes an instance of `Currency` implicitly convertible to `double`. Here are two examples where `operator double()` is used:

```cpp
Currency cur{1, 2};

double d = cur; // this works, d is now 1.02

std::cout << cur << '\n'; // and even this (and prints 1.02)
```